# Controlling GIFs in Microsoft Word generated HTML

Tags: javascript, animation, gif

I am not an HTML guy - I am strictly a Java and C# programmer. I am trying to write a manual for some software. I used Word, and it worked pretty well. It has embedded animated GIFs.

I want to export it so I can distribute the manual. If I export as PDF, the GIFs are turned into static images. If I export as HTML the GIFs animate, but they start animating when the page is shown and not when the user is ready to see the animation. Even Facebook has a button to start and stop a GIF animation.

I know there are some javascript libs that purport to do what I want, but I'm not familiar enough with HTML to manually edit the Word output.  Is there a simple piece of javascript (or maybe two pieces) that I can just paste in at the top of the Word-generated file with will update the DOM and provide me the functionality I need?  I not only need to know what the JS is but also where to paste it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? If you're at the degree of knowledgeness of JS insomuch to blindy copy-paste the code, how in the world are you supposed to know _how_ to control the gif with JS?

Comment: I understand that JS can go through the DOM and modify things on the fly. The 'control' I want is for the end user to be able to start and stop the GIF from animating.